# MySQL Long Query Statement despite Index

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT Frage_ID FROM Session_Fragen WHERE (Userantwort1 = 0 
AND Userantwort2 = 0 AND Userantwort3 = 0 AND Userantwort4 = 0 
AND Userantwort5 = 0) AND Session_ID = 12946 
ORDER BY Sessionfrage_ID ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Table: Session_Fragen has approx. 560.000 rows (and is growing  1.000 to 4.000 rows a day...)

The query above takes actually 1.5 seconds.

After I realized this, I tried using Indexes..

---

```
SHOW INDEXES FROM Session_Fragen
```

gives me this:

```
Table           Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name         Collation   Cardinality     Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment

Session_Fragen  0           PRIMARY     1               Sessionfrage_ID     A            567108         NULL        NULL        BTREE   

Session_Fragen  1           Frage_ID    1               Frage_ID            A            2849           NULL        NULL        BTREE
```

---

When I use `EXPLAIN` response is:

```
id  select_type     table           type    possible_keys   key        key_len  ref     rows    Extra

1   SIMPLE          Session_Fragen  index   NULL            PRIMARY     8       NULL    1   Using where
```

---

I can't figure it out, how to improve this statement to speed up.
Any other possibilities than indexes?

Thank you all for your help!

EDIT:
SHOW CREATE TABLE Session_Fragen

Table   Create Table
Session_Fragen  CREATE TABLE `Session_Fragen` (
 `Sessionfrage_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `User_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `SF_Timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `Session_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Frage_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Userantwort1` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `Userantwort2` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `Userantwort3` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `Userantwort4` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `Userantwort5` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`Sessionfrage_ID`),
 KEY `Frage_ID` (`Frage_ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=753863 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: Removed sql-server tag because question is explicitly about MySQL.

Comment: Can you post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE Session_Fragen`, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `where` clause has all equality comparisons.  Try the following index:

```
create index Session_Fragen_big_idx on Session_Fragen(Session_id, Userantwort1, Userantwort2, Userantwort3,
                                                      Userantwort4, Userantwort5, Sessionfrage_ID, Frage_ID
                                                     );
```

This index completely "covers" the query, so it can be used instead of the actual data.  I should note that having multiple columns with similar names (`Userantwort1` and so on) is a bad sign -- even when I personally don't understand what the column names mean.  This typically suggests that you want an association/junction table.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess without the table structure, if you could post it it migth help to find the problem. To me your index seem ok, since you have the PRIMARY_KEY in your where, MySQL should normaly be able to return the row rigth away, i don't have the rigth table structure, but in this example, you can see that the Optimizer is simply changing your query to return the data you need :

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED
SELECT Frage_ID FROM Session_Fragen WHERE (Userantwort1 = 0 
AND Userantwort2 = 0 AND Userantwort3 = 0 AND Userantwort4 = 0 ) AND Session_ID = 12946 
ORDER BY Session_ID ASC LIMIT 1;
SHOW WARNINGS
```

Will change to

```
select '3' AS `Frage_ID` from `test`.`Session_Fragen` where 1 order by '12946' limit 1
```

Comment: Added Table Structure

Comment: The Comment from Gordon Linoff is rigth, i tough the primary key was on Session_Id and not Sessionfrage_ID, adding an index on Session_Id should improve the performance of your query.